# PDF Converter for use from .net application

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

We have a project where we need to convert the following file types to PDF:

- application/msword  .doc
- application/rtf  .rtf
- application/vnd.ms-excel  .xls
- application/vnd.ms-powerpoint  .ppt
- application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  .odp
- application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet  .ods
- application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text  .odt
- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  .pptx
- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet  .xlsx
- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document  .docx
- application/vnd.sun.xml.calc  .sxc
- application/vnd.sun.xml.writer  .sxw
- text/html  .html
- text/plain  .txt

We have found a number of tools / products, but none that can convert from all formats.

We would prefer a tool that had a .net API and could take a document as a byte array.

Does anyone have any product / tool that they would recomend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have used Aspose tools in many of our products and found them to be very good indeed. [Aspose.com](http://www.aspose.com/)

Comment: Further to this though, you'll probably not find anything that will convert everything.  You may have to use some other converter in between before converting to pdf for some of them.

Comment: Yup, Aspose is the best of the pack that we've seen too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Neevias [Document Converter Pro](http://www.neevia.com/products/dcpro/)?

It basically "prints" the documents to it's own printer, and converts the output to PDF.
Therefore, anything you can print you can convert to PDF.

We have sites where it processes +50,000 documents per day.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [PDF Converter Services](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx). It runs as a Windows Service and can be accessed via a web services Interface so works with .net as well as Java.

It supports the majority of your formats. See [this example](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html).

Note that I have worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply.